# Checkout SVN in folder with different name

Tags: svn, repository, version, versioning

I have a repository:

SERVER/DH/

On my local machine

~/TeX/

I want to put the TeX folder in the repository as SERVER/DH/TeX

without having my local folder changed to ~/DH/TeX so keeping ~/TeX

whenever I do checkout svn co sv://.../DH it creates the DH folder on in my home. How do I do this? Am I able to create an extra repo under /DH? Could I do this with svn commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import a local (non-versioned) directory to the repository with the svn import command:

```
svn import -m "Import folder TeX" ~/TeX svn://SERVER/DH/TeX
```

After that, you can do a checkout to your local folder again. Now, you might be able to do this on existing folder using the `--force` flag:

```
svn co --force svn://SERVER/DH/TeX ~/TeX
```

However, I'd recommend backing up your local folder and performing a fresh checkout:

```
mv ~/TeX ~/TeX_bak
svn co svn://SERVER/DH/TeX ~/TeX
```